# Dell Laptop WiFi Stops working after an hour

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-inspiron

Hi I have a Dell inspiron 15 5000 series. Ever since the beginning, it has a strange issue of: I'll be using it for about 1 hour to 2 hours, the Internet all the sudden will become very slow (the wifi connection still shows connected, but it slows to the point where you got no response). Then after I reboot it, it will start working normal again and then stop working again after 2 hours. This laptop is about 1 year old, and the problem is a problem from the beginning.

I have tried the following myself already:
- try to update to the latest WiFi driver for my dell laptop.
- try updates everything in the OS to the latest
- Try disconnect and re-connect (without rebooting laptop) when the issue comes on.

I suspect there's something wrong either with the wireless adapter in the laptop, or some kind of driver or software bugs that at the beginning it would work, after you use it for a while, it fills up something that don't clear.

I'm running windows 8.1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what was wrong. It appears to be the driver of wireless adapter. I downloaded the dell update tool and it installed 3 updates (not sure what are installed since the Dell update tool shows you no details). I rebooted, and the problem seems to go away for now.

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect there's something wrong either with ... some kind of ... software bugs ...

What's the CPU / hard disk usage look like right around when the WiFi slows / stops? Start task manager (TaskMgr.exe) and on the Processes tab sort on CPU usage so that the higher percentages are at the top. Note which processes are demanding the highest CPU usage - investigate any that are not M$/W8 specific.

If you're certain you have Dell's latest NIC drivers then I suggest installing Avast (http://download.cnet.com/Avast-Free-Antivirus-2015/3001-2239_4-10019223.html) or equivalent AV software. Avast works really well at obliterating virii / malware.

Comment: It's happening again just now. I check the task manager, nothing in particular caught my eye. The CPU is fairly subdued in around 2% to 3%, the highest CPU process is the chrome process which I'm trying to access a website. Strangely, I type in amazon.com to the chrome browse, the browse shows "Resolving host" it takes longer than usual. On my other PC on the same wireless network, it brings up same website amazon in a flash, loaded everything quickly. While on dell laptop, it's getting slow, it shows a few of elements of the page, still loading after like 5 minutes later. Before, it was ok.